# Scala - state while looping through a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Newbie question.
I am looping through a list and need keep state in between the items. 
For instance

```
  val l = List("a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "4")
  var state: String = ""
  l.foreach(o => {
    if (toInt(o).isEmpty) state = o else println(state + o.toString)
  })
```

what's the alternative for the usage of var here?

Comment: Can you give us an example of code that didn't work? I think I know what you're asking but I'm unclear.

Comment: `foldLeft` is what is used in FP to keep state

Comment: @wheaties - I have changed the question to include a code sample, I believe it is clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should keep in mind that it's sometimes (read: when it makes the code more readable and maintainable by others) okay to use mutability when performing some operation that's easily expressed with mutable state as long as that mutable state is confined to as little of your program as possible. Using (e.g.) `foldLeft` to maintain an accumulator here without using a `var` doesn't gain you much.

That said, here's one way to go about doing this:

```scala
val listOfThings: Seq[Either[Char, Int]] = Seq(Left('a'), Right(11), Right(212), Left('b'), Right(89))

val result = listOfThings.foldLeft(Seq[(Char, Seq[Int])]()) {
  case (accumulator, Left(nextChar)) => accumulator :+ (nextChar, Seq.empty)
  case (accumulator, Right(nextInt)) =>
    val (currentChar, currentSequence) = accumulator.last
    accumulator.dropRight(1) :+ (currentChar, currentSequence :+ nextInt)
}

result foreach {
  case (char, numbers) => println(numbers.map(num => s"$char-$num").mkString(" "))
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to take `last` or append to `List`, much better to reverse it or use `ListBuffer`

Comment: Also I would argue that imperative solution will not be much more readable than yours (provided that you want to keep `result` as a variable).

Answer (score 2):

Use `foldLeft`:

```
l.foldLeft(""){ (state, o) => 
  if(toInt(o).isEmpty) o 
  else {
    println(state + o.toString)
    state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an arg:

```
scala> def collapse(header: String, vs: List[String]): Unit = vs match {
     | case Nil =>
     | case h :: t if h.forall(Character.isDigit) => println(s"$header$h") ; collapse(header, t)
     | case h :: t => collapse(h, t)
     | }
collapse: (header: String, vs: List[String])Unit

scala> collapse("", vs)
a1
a2
a3
b4
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two major options to pass a state in functional programming when processing collections (I assume you want to get your result as a variable):

**Recursion (classic)**

```
val xs = List("a", "11", "212", "b", "89")

@annotation.tailrec
def fold(seq: ListBuffer[(String, ListBuffer[String])], 
         xs: Seq[String]): ListBuffer[(String, ListBuffer[String])] = {
  (seq, xs) match {
    case (_, Nil) =>
      seq
    case (_, c :: tail) if toInt(c).isEmpty  =>
      fold(seq :+ ((c, ListBuffer[String]())), tail)
    case (init :+ ((c, seq)), i :: tail) =>
      fold(init :+ ((c, seq :+ i)), tail)

  }
}

val result =
  fold(ListBuffer[(String, ListBuffer[String])](), xs)
  // Get rid of mutable ListBuffer
  .toSeq
  .map { 
    case (c, seq) => 
      (c, seq.toSeq)
  }
  //> List((a,List(11, 212)), (b,List(89)))
```

**foldLeft** et al.

```
val xs = List("a", "11", "212", "b", "89")

val result = 
  xs.foldLeft(
    ListBuffer[(String, ListBuffer[String])]()
  ) {
    case (seq, c) if toInt(c).isEmpty  =>
      seq :+ ((c, ListBuffer[String]()))
    case (init :+ ((c, seq)), i) =>
      init :+ ((c, seq :+ i))
  }
  // Get rid of mutable ListBuffer
  .toSeq
  .map { 
    case (c, seq) => 
      (c, seq.toSeq)
  }
  //> List((a,List(11, 212)), (b,List(89)))
```

Which one is better? Unless you want to abort your processing in the middle of your collection (like e.g. in `find`) `foldLeft` is considered a better way and it has slightly less boilerplate, but otherwise they are very similar.

I'm using `ListBuffer` here to avoid reversing lists.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
val list: List[Int] = List.range(1, 10) // Create list

def updateState(i : Int) : Int = i + 1 // Generate new state, just add one to each position. That will be the state

list.foldRight[List[(Int,Int)]](List())((a, b) => (a, updateState(a)) :: b)
```

Note that the result is a list of Tuple2: (Element, State), and each state depends on the element of the list.

Hope this helps